# using a variable to assign a property in c#?

Tags: c#, properties.settings

I have some properties set in the settings of a c# application.  I am using them to store a string.  My problem is i want to call them based on the name variable of the class.

So i want to do something like this

```
Description = Properties.Settings.Default.(name + "Description");
```

Is this possible?  Or do i have to write a nasty switch statement based off the the name property?

```
Swith(name)
case:name1 
 Description = properties.settings.default.name1Descrition;
```

Comment: You can use reflection for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about Winforms, `Properties.Settings.Default` is an indexable collection, so you just need to get it by key:

```
var Description = Properties.Settings.Default[name + "Description"] as string;
```

You don't need to use reflection, it is retrievable either way. You are close in your first guess.

Using the indexer to get the value always returns an `object` so you need to cast it to the final type (the `as string`) or whatever type the property is.

Comment: Thank you this worked.  I looked into reflection and wrote a good foreach loop,  their was a wierd bug however and the setting.default.propertyvalues was null the first loop through.  I was about to have to make it way more complicated than it needed to be.  Thank you!